# Can litigants in person claim other costs than their time?

Tags: england-and-wales, civil-law, costs, litigant-in-person

Suppose an in person litigant wins their case. Now suppose they wish to seek costs from their counterpart. Typically this is assessed at £19ph. But what if this litigant was disabled, for example paralysed or with polio? And required a scribe who was to be paid hourly in order to write for them? Or a general aid to help them around as they work?

Or what if they weren’t so disabled, but had paid a personal assistant a certain rate in order to assist them in legal research, or they had purchased costly subscriptions to legal research databases in order to support their preparation of their case?

Are any of these costs recoverable by an in person litigant?

Comment: It is worth noting that in U.S. law, such litigants can almost never recover the costs of their own time, even in circumstances when attorney fees are available to a prevailling party.

Comment: When you have the "American rule" of no fee shifting as a default it flows pretty naturally.

Comment: Well in the general case I certainly see that, but not in the exceptional circumstances you’ve mentioned of attorney fees being recoverable. Why aren’t self represented time costs recoverable in such circumstances? And I wonder why my previous question-comment seems to have been deleted.

Comment: It has simply been the law since time immemorial and no one has mobilized to change it by statute.